# Insert string every nth element in a list of strings

Tags: clojure, lisp

I'm new to Clojure.

I'm developing a tic tac toe game

I'm trying to make a function that "formats" the board, which is a map with the number of the position as key and the keywords `:x` `:o` and `:e` for values (:e stands for empty).

---

I want to insert a newline character every 3 in the list of the name of the keywords.

For example `"x" "x" "x" "e" "e" "e" "e" "e" "e"` should be converted to `"x" "x" "x" "\n" "e" "e" "e" "\n" "e" "e" "e"` then I would concatenate those strings so I can print it.

```
(defn- newline-every
  [n list]
  (if (empty? list)
    []
    (let [[fst snd] (split-at n list)]
      (concat
        (conj fst "\n")
        (newline-every n snd)))))
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Well, this is embarassing, seems like the REPL got bugged or something, but now there is no error. But it gives a wrong output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's Clojure so there are surely many ways to do this in one line. Here's one attempt:

```
(flatten (interpose "\n" (partition n list))))
```

As user *amalloy* commented, there's never an excuse to use `flatten`, so here's a better way:

```
(apply concat (interpose ["\n"] (partition n list))))
```

Which gives, starting from the sequence of strings (which all contain one character) you gave:

```
... > (newline-every 3 ["x" "x" "x" "e" "e" "e" "e" "e" "e"])
("x" "x" "x" "\n" "e" "e" "e" "\n" "e" "e" "e")
```

You can then transform that into a string:

```
... > (apply str (newline-every 3 ["x" "x" "x" "e" "e" "e" "e" "e" "e"]))
"xxx\neee\neee"
```

Comment: This is not bad, but there's really never an excuse to use `flatten`. Instead, you can write something like `(apply str (apply concat (interpose ["\n"] (partition n list))))`

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if `list`'s length is not a multiple of `n`, then it doesn't work as expected.